# How to remove trailing whitespace of an element in contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, contenteditable

I been trying for sometime now , please find my work till now below.

```
/**
     * @param {any} container contenteditable container
     * @param {any} node  element contained inside the container for which we need to 
     * remove the space from
     */
    function removeTrailingSpace(container,node){
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            var sel = window.getSelection(), range;
            if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
                range.collapse(true);
                range.setStartAfter(node);
                range.setEnd(container, 1);

                var rString = range.toString();
                var sChar = range.toString().length > 0 ? rString[0] : null;

                if (sChar && sChar.trim() === '') {
                    console.log("TRAILING SPACE FOUND");
                    range.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset + 1);
                    range.deleteContents();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**To be more specific ,I need to remove "&nbsp" after button element from the contenteditable div.**

[image]

**Any Suggestion would be much appreciated .
Thanks**

Comment: Can't you just use element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.trim() ?

Comment: I just need to remove a single space after a particular element contained in the contenteditable div.

Comment: You want to remove space after `@` ?  can you be just more clear ?

Comment: please see my edits , added some more details.

Comment: You might be appending the space while  appending button to the  contentEditable div ?

Comment: yes , you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to your problem, the whitespace you are trying to remove is actually a text node. Please try the code below:

```
function removeTrailingSpace(container, node) {
    const values = Array.from(container.childNodes.values());
    const value = values.find(x => x === node);
    const index = values.indexOf(value);
    const nextNode = container.childNodes[index + 1];
    if(nextNode.nodeValue.length === 1 && nextNode.nodeValue.charCodeAt(0) === 160) {
        console.log('Whitespace found, removing...');
        container.removeChild(nextNode);
    }
}
```